# OkHttpClient "open" method missing in v2.0

Tags: android, okhttp

If you are upgrading from OkHttp library from 1.x to 2.x, glaringly the OkHttpClient method "open" is missing. The below code will NOT compile.

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        HttpURLConnection conn = client.open(url);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the official [change log](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

URLConnection support has moved to the okhttp-urlconnection module. If you're upgrading from 1.x, this change will impact you. You will need to add the okhttp-urlconnection module to your project and use the OkUrlFactory to create new instances of HttpURLConnection:

```
// OkHttp 1.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);

// OkHttp 2.x:
HttpURLConnection connection = new OkUrlFactory(client).open(url);
```

Just remember to add the dependency as below to the Gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

As of OkHttp 3.x, `OkUrlFactory` had been marked deprecated, in favor of the new `Request/Response` style of calls, which is more flexible. Some info: https://publicobject.com/2015/12/15/okurlfactory-is-going-away/

So the new style is going to look more like:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient()

Request request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build()
Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()
```